# How do I mount my code to a container, and then run it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, volumes

I have a dockerfile, which was in a working state before I tried using volumes.  The dockerfile is very simple like this:

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7
RUN #compile some code
CMD #run the code
```

#### docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  myApp:
    build: myApp
    volumes: 
      - type: bind
      - source: ./myApp
      - target: /myApp
```

During the `RUN` phase of the `Dockerfile` it says the code does not exist at `/myapp`.  When I exec into the container, the directory does exist, so I'm pretty confident, that it's mounting the code after it tries both `CMD` and `RUN`.  Is there a way to mount the code before I try running the code?

This is just for faster development testing for integration with another app.  Meaning, I want to run my code without having to rebuild the entire thing every time.  So, solutions that use only docker, and not docker-compose won't really help me that much (I don't think).

---

## EDIT 1

I tried using the `command` keyword similar to the following:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  myApp:
    build: myApp
    volumes: 
      - type: bind
      - source: ./myApp
      - target: /myApp
    command: javac -d /myApp/path/to/classDir /path/to/x.java
```

While the command does seem to work with some commands, I haven't figured out how it works exactly.

For example, I can have `command: touch /myApp/path/to/somewhere/test.txt` and it does run, and that directory does exist, but if I run a command like the one above (the javac command), the same path doesn't exist with javac.  So, it can touch those directories, but it says the directory doesn't exist if I try and execute or compile something from the same directory.  Still figuring it out.

Comment: The mount happens, when the container based on the image is started, this is at run time. The image build (using the Dockerfile) happens before that. You need to add a COPY of your source in the Dockerfile to make it available at build time.

Comment: `CMD` does not do anything during the image build. It sets the default arguments for the entrypoint of the image and only has an effect when the image is run. You should use the `COPY` instruction to copy the source into the image before compiling.

Comment: @Henry  If I use COPY, then I thought COPY only runs when I rebuild, correct?

Comment: I could be wrong, since I'm new to this, but when I did COPY, then running `docker-compose up`, and down, don't alter the code at all, I have to rebuild with no cache.  And that's not really useful in my use case.

Comment: @jakub Thanks, and yes, I got the `CMD` and `RUN` backwards.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are trying to do. Start the container interactively with your host directory with the source mounted and run a bash in it. Then you can enter commands as you like.

Comment: @Henry That is a solution, but I was really hoping for something more automated.  But, if there's no way to mount the code, then run commands on it, that may be what I have to do.

Comment: It looks like I could possibly use the `command` keyword in the `docker-compose` file.  That appears to run after the mount happens.  Checking now.